# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the following peace of code to get the edge map from a tensor image or images but I am getting the error, how we can solve it? I am using TensorFlow version 2.4 and python version 3.7.

Used Code:

```
image_GT = [image_GT]
aperture_size = 7
t_lower = 0  # Lower Threshold
t_upper = 1
print("image_GT[0].shape: ", image_GT[0].shape) 
image = image_GT[0][0] 
print("type(image): ", type(image))     
print("image.shape: ", image.shape)        
image = tf.make_ndarray(image)
image = cv2.Canny(image, t_lower, t_upper, apertureSize=aperture_size)
```

Output with error:

```
image_GT[0].shape:  (16, 256, 256, 3)
type(image):  <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
image.shape:  (256, 256, 3)

/Code/aiisp_base.py:962 calc_losses_EdgeNet1  *
image = tf.make_ndarray(image)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:597 MakeNdarray  **
shape = [d.size for d in tensor.tensor_shape.dim]

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape'
```

Answer (score 1):

`tf.make_ndarray` takes only `TensorProto` as input, so you need to convert the Tensor to `tf.make_tensor_proto`

```
image = tf.make_ndarray(tf.make_tensor_proto(image))
```

You can just do `image = image.numpy()` instead.

Comment: I am getting the following error if I am using  image = tf.make_ndarray(tf.make_tensor_proto(image)) TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, got a tensor instead.

Comment: I have already used image = image.numpy() but getting the error : AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: both code instructions are not useful in my code.

Comment: the image variable already contain the image tensor

Comment: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' error : You should enable eagar mode. If you are using model.fit() enable it by `model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`

Answer (score 0):

According to [javidcf on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28840#issuecomment-1083326444) (emphasis mine):

> [`tf.make_ndarray`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_ndarray) is NOT a general function to convert tensors to
> NumPy arrays (in spite to what the admittedly misleading documentation
> of the function might say). What it does is it converts a
> [`TensorProto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.8.0/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.proto), which is a low-level binary representation of a
> tensor, into a NumPy array. Most typical TensorFlow code will never
> use [`TensorProto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.8.0/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.proto) objects (directly), so [`tf.make_ndarray`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_ndarray) is just
> not a useful function for most people. Depending on the case, it may
> be possible to build a NumPy array from a tensor with it, but, again,
> its purpose is not to convert tensors to NumPy arrays in general, and
> it should rarely or never be used.
>
> If you want to convert a TensorFlow tensor into a NumPy array, you
> need to be mindful that TensorFlow code may run in **eager mode** or
> **graph mode**. **Graph mode** is less "convenient" to use, but it is important for performance, optimisation, serialisation and other
> reasons. Although it is rare to explicitly enter into graph mode as a
> library user, it is very normal to write code that runs in graph mode,
> like the code in a Keras model, for example. It is not always
> straightforward to know what mode your code is running, especially
> since TensorFlow aims to hide this complexity from the library users,
> but the complexity is still there and it is important to understand
> it.
>
> If you are in **eager mode**, you can just do `.numpy()` on your
> tensor. In **graph mode**, though, you CANNOT obtain the NumPy array
> corresponding to a tensor, because tensors do not hold any value in
> particular in graph mode, but they rather expresses a symbolic
> intermediate results (with some exceptions like [`tf.constant`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant), which
> is possible to convert into a NumPy array even in **graph mode**,
> because it always has the same value). If you want to do a NumPy
> operation with your tensor in **graph mode** (which would not be
> differentiable in TensorFlow btw), you need to temporarily switch to
> **eager mode** within **graph mode**, which you can do with [`tf.py_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function). There, your tensors will be eager tensors and you
> can call `.numpy()` on them.